# How to find number of lines changed between CVS versions?

Tags: diff, cvs

I've spent most of the day making what are basically some housekeeping changes to the codebase of one of our projects (replacing all `System.out.println()` calls with log4j).

I'm kind of curious how many lines of code I've updated with this set of changes.

Is there anyway with `cvs diff` or another command to get an accurate count of how many lines have changed?

I've tried

```
cvs diff -b -B -R
```

to get all of the changes in the working directory (and recursively the subdirectories), but for each file changed it also prints out file/version information, which makes just counting the lines of output useless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out extra lines from the diff output and then count the lines.

For example, grep only lines starting with < or >

```
cvs diff -b -B -R | egrep '^<|>' | wc -l
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using after all, a few seconds before you posted - thanks

Answer (score 5):

The [diffstat](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/) utility is a nice tool for getting some simple metrics from the output of cvs, svn or other diffs.

Comment: diffstat worked for me.  On Windows, I installed Cygwin and selected the diffstat and cvs from the devel group.  The command invocation looks like cvs diff -r 1.1.6.1 -r 1.1.6.4 "Some File" | diffstat -m

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pipe output of cvs diff to diffstat.

Comment: This works well, although it seems to double-count files like "jsp/blah.jsp" and "blah.jsp". Didn't know about diffstat before, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about verify that you've changed all instances with something like:

```
find . | egrep -v -e '(CVS|<other patterns you don't want>)' | \
    xargs egrep -e 'System\.out\.println[(][)]' | wc -l
```

that should give you zero.

Then replacing the regex in the second egrep with 'log4j' should have wc -l returning the number of lines you've changed.

HTH.

cheers,

Rob